# how to make a Gif image take the full screen (resizable)?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, gif

I'm using a gif image as a Splash page ,but when i try to simulated with the Big screen (10.5") it fit not the full screen.

My Splash page layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    tools:context=".Splash">

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/fneclis_splash_bg" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My code :

```
class Splash : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //hiding title bar of this activity
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        //making this activity full screen
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        //2.63second splash time
        Handler().postDelayed({
            //start main activity
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
            //finish this activity
            finish()
        },2630)    

        val gib = GifImageButton(this)
        setContentView(gib)
        gib.setImageResource(R.drawable.fneclis_splash_bg)
        val mc = MediaController(this)
        mc.setMediaPlayer(gib.drawable as GifDrawable)
        mc.setAnchorView(gib)
        gib.setOnClickListener(object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                mc.show()
            }

            override fun onClick(p0: DialogInterface?, p1: Int) {
                mc.show()
            }    
        })    
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to add a gif image to android studio ???

**HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEELP !!**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the GifImageView:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: the same problem brother !!